# Indexing with custom sort order and subentries

Tags: luatex, imakeidx

I'm using LuaLaTeX to generate a sort key override the default sort order for bidding sequences.  The simpler entries look like e.g. \index[seq]{1T-1K}, \index[seq]{1T-1C}, \index[seq]{1SA-2T} representing an opening of 1 Club (Trèfles) with a response of 1 Diamond (K=Carreaux) so the primary sort order is on the level of the bid (a digit 1--7) and then on the suit (T, K, C, P, SA).

So I generate a key based on these e.g. 2G3A is for a 2SA-3T sequence which will sort before the 2G3D is for a 2SA-3P sequence and after 1A2B for a 1T-2K sequence.

Now I generate sequences which continue on from this starting point e.g. 2SA-3T ; 3K-3C will generate a key 2G3A3B3C etc and these sort correctly.

But what I would like to do is have this as a sub-entry in the index, and I've generated a "!" which is inserted into the entry at the appropriate point (the ";" which marks the continuation point.

This partially works, and gives an index with repeated main terms e.g.

```
Liste des Séquences
2SA-3T, 1
2SA-3T;3K, 1
2SA-3T;3K-3C, 1
2SA-3T;3K-3C;3P, 1
2SA-3T;3K-3C;3SA, 1 
2SA-3T;3SA, 1
```

I would like to remove the duplicate root entries and get something more like

```
2SA–3T: 1
  3K, 1
  3K–3C, 1
  3K-3C;3P, 1
  3K-3C;3SA, 1 
  3SA, 1
```

I'm not sure what to do to correct the main entry - subentry issue.

This is the sort of result I want

```
Page 7: \index{gnat!size of}
Page 32: \index{gnat}
Page 35: \index{gnat!anatomy}
\index{gnus!good}
Page 38: \index{gnus!bad}

gnat, 32
    anatomy, 35
    size of, 7
gnus
    bad, 38
    good, 35
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%                                                                      

\RequirePackage[para]{threeparttable}%
\RequirePackage{imakeidx}\makeindex%
\RequirePackage[unbalanced,indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}%

\RequirePackage{luacode}%

\directlua{require "lualoader"%
assert(loadfile("TeXmacros.lua"))("French")%
}%

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bsort}[1]{\directlua{Bsort([[#1]])}}%
\makeindex[name=seq,title=Liste des Séquences]

\begin{document}                                                                


\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}                                                                                                                              
2xxx    &3xxx   &\Bsort{2SA-3T}\\                                                             
3xxx    &       &\\                                                             
&3K   &Chassé-croisé\Bsort{2SA-3T;3K} \\                                            
&3SA                   &A jouer ;\Bsort{2SA-3T;3SA}\\                                                                                                                                             
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx   &3xxx   &Chassé-croisé ;\Bsort{2SA-3T;3K-3C}\\                                               
3xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, en attendant ;\Bsort{2SA-3T;3K-3C;3P}\\                               
3xxx    &       &Sans fit xxx xxx{3},  \Bsort{2SA-3T;3K-3C;3SA}\\                                      
\end{tabular}                                                                                            
\end{threeparttable}                                                            

\printindex[seq]         
\end{document}                                                                  

function Bsort(s)
--Patch the index to use Bridge sort order
    local t=""

    --Generate a sort key for the input sequence.
    for c in s:gmatch"." do
        if tonumber(c) ~= nil then
            t = t .. c
        end

        if c == "T" then
          t = t .. "A"
       end
        if c == "K" then
          t = t .. "B"
       end
        if c == "C" then
          t = t .. "C"
       end
        if c == "P" then
          t = t .. "D"
       end
        if c == "m" then
          t = t .. "E"
       end
        if c == "M" then
          t = t .. "F"
       end
        if c == "S" then
          t = t .. "G"
       end
    end

    --Section the index. 
    s = string.gsub(s, ";", "!;")

    --Prefix the index with the sort order.
    s = t .. "@" .. s

    -- Write the index back to LuaLaTeX.
    s = "\\index[seq]{" .. s .. "}"
    tex.sprint(s)
    return s
end
```

seq.idx

```
  \indexentry{2G3A@2SA-3T}{1}
\indexentry{2G3A3B@2SA-3T!; 3K}{1}
\indexentry{2G3A3G@2SA-3T!; 3SA}{1}
\indexentry{2G3A3B3C@2SA-3T!; 3K-3C}{1}
\indexentry{2G3A3B3C3D@2SA-3T!; 3K-3C!; 3P}{1}
\indexentry{2G3A3B3C3G@2SA-3T!; 3K-3C!; 3SA}{1}
```

Comment: A minimal but compilable example is needed.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't tell *how* those entries are generated.

Comment: @egreg I can post the lua function that generates these, but I'm not sure that helps.  The issue is what should those index entries look like to produce a properly nested item - subitem printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details about the syntax for indices in the man page of makeindex.
In your case, a separate sort index has to be provided for every level, so instead of

```
\index{2G3A3B@2SA-3T!; 3K}
```

you need

```
\index{2G3A@2SA-3T!3B@3K}
```

They can be generated like this:

```
\documentclass{article}%                                                                      

\RequirePackage[para]{threeparttable}%
\RequirePackage{imakeidx}\makeindex%
\RequirePackage[unbalanced,indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}%

\RequirePackage{luacode}%

\begin{luacode*}
function Bsort(s)
--Patch the index to use Bridge sort order
  local maxdepth = 2
  local t, u = "", ""

  --Generate a sort key for the input sequence.
  for c in s:gmatch"." do
    t = t .. (tonumber(c)
           or ({ T = "A",
                 K = "B",
                 C = "C",
                 P = "D",
                 m = "E",
                 M = "M",
                 S = "G"
              })[c] or "")
    if maxdepth > 0 and c == ";" then
      t = t .. "@" .. u .. "!"
      u = ""
      maxdepth = maxdepth - 1
    else
      u = u .. c
    end
  end

  -- Write the index back to LuaLaTeX.
  s = "\\index[seq]{" .. t .. "@" .. u .. "}"
  tex.sprint(s)
  return s
end
\end{luacode*}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bsort}[1]{\directlua{Bsort("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}%
\makeindex[name=seq,title=Liste des Séquences]

\begin{document}                                                                


\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}                                                                                                                              
2xxx    &3xxx   &\Bsort{2SA-3T}\\                                                             
3xxx    &       &\\                                                             
&3K   &Chassé-croisé\Bsort{2SA-3T;3K} \\                                            
&3SA                   &A jouer ;\Bsort{2SA-3T;3SA}\\                                                                                                                                             
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx   &3xxx   &Chassé-croisé ;\Bsort{2SA-3T;3K-3C}\\                                               
3xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, en attendant ;\Bsort{2SA-3T;3K-3C;3P}\\                               
3xxx    &       &Sans fit xxx xxx{3},  \Bsort{2SA-3T;3K-3C;3SA}\\                                      
\end{tabular}                                                                                            
\end{threeparttable}                                                            

\printindex[seq]         
\end{document}
```

[image]
If you only want one level of nesting, you can change `maxdepth` to `1` to get
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.